# update records on target table based on unique key In dbt (data build tool)

Tags: dbt

If dbt model is not incremental but simply I want to insert and update records on target table based on unique key  In dbt (data build tool)

Comment: Could you give more details? the context of your problem, some examples?

Comment: @HuiZheng Thanks I got that resolved , I just had to build incremental model and define uniquekey

Answer (score 2):

{{
config(
materialized='incremental',
unique_key='Id'
)
}}

we just have to mention the uniekey and the model as incremental and write select query , dbt transforms it into merge query